# Остается ли итератор на элемент std::list корректным при переносе элемента в другой список?

Tags: c++, list, итераторы

Скажите, пожалуйста, остается ли итератор на элемент `std::list<T>` корректным при переносе элемента в другой список?

Comment: Покажите код, который делает перенос.

Comment: [Adding, removing and moving the elements within the list or across several lists does not invalidate the iterators or references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переношу в ответ комментарий dIm0n:

Как указано [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list),

> Добавление, удаление и перемещение элементов в списке или между несколькими списками не делает недействительными итераторы или ссылки. Итератор становится недействительным только при удалении соответствующего элемента.

Так что если это именно *перенос* - то итератор остается корректным.